# Internal Mic only capturing Static Noise in Asus Laptop (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, hda-intel

I have been struggling with this issue for a long time. My internal mic is just capturing Static Noise and not responding to any sound waves at all. And upon recording i hear only those static noise.

Here is the alsa hw info for my machine:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0e9c9e0f8168da20003e325086c296240976ed7b

I suspect that the pins for the Internal Mic and Pluggable Microphone in my laptops swapped. But even after playing with **hdajackretask** quite a bit, it is still the same.

Thanks so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Run pulse audio control. Likely wrong mic device is being used. From terminal, run 'pavucontrol'. In my experience, when sound input is wrong, answer is visible here. Input mat be listening on a headphone jack, for example.